# update sql incorrect syntax from

Tags: sql-server

```
Update  s
Set s.ServiceDeliverySettingID = 
                                Case  
                                When s.HCCMRRServiceType  = '01' Then (Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                                                     Where HCCValue = '08')
                                When s.HCCMRRServiceType in ('02','10') Then ( Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                                                     Where HCCValue = '01')
                                When s.HCCMRRServiceType  = '06' Then (Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                                                     Where HCCValue = '97')
                                When s.HCCMRRServiceType in ('08','11') Then ( Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                                                     Where HCCValue = '10')
                                When s.HCCMRRServiceType  = '14' Then (Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                                                     Where HCCValue = '05')
                                When s.HCCMRRServiceType = '51' Then (Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                                             Where HCCValue = '06') 
                                When s.HCCMRRServiceType = '50' 

                                Then

                                case 

                                   when s.InterventionCode = 'ICR' then ( Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                                             Where HCCValue = '97')
                                   when s.InterventionCode = 'RC' then ( Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                                             Where HCCValue = '06')
                                    when s.InterventionCode = 'ICFCH' then ( Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                                             Where HCCValue = '02')



                              End
From [DSDW].[Staging].[HCCMRRBuildService] s
```

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'.

Can anyone please help me explain why I am getting the error message, when I execute the above update query?

Comment: can anyone please help me explain why I am getting the error message, when I execute the above update query?

Comment: Count the number of instances of the word `CASE` and then count the number of instances of the word `END`. Better formatting and indenting might have made the issue more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first look, you have a nested CASE, but i only see a single END.  You need to add one more END to finish off the parent set of CASE statements.

Comment: great thanks, I feel silly :)

Answer (score 3):

You have an `END` missing

```
Update  s
Set s.ServiceDeliverySettingID = 
        Case  
        When s.HCCMRRServiceType  = '01' Then (Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                             Where HCCValue = '08')
        When s.HCCMRRServiceType in ('02','10') Then ( Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                             Where HCCValue = '01')
        When s.HCCMRRServiceType  = '06' Then (Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                             Where HCCValue = '97')
        When s.HCCMRRServiceType in ('08','11') Then ( Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                             Where HCCValue = '10')
        When s.HCCMRRServiceType  = '14' Then (Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                             Where HCCValue = '05')
        When s.HCCMRRServiceType = '51' Then (Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                     Where HCCValue = '06') 
        When s.HCCMRRServiceType = '50' 

        Then
          case 
           when s.InterventionCode = 'ICR' then ( Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                     Where HCCValue = '97')
           when s.InterventionCode = 'RC' then ( Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                     Where HCCValue = '06')
            when s.InterventionCode = 'ICFCH' then ( Select ServiceDeliverySettingID from [DSDW].[Dim].[ServiceDeliverySetting]
                                     Where HCCValue = '02')
           END   --<-- this was missing
      End
From [DSDW].[Staging].[HCCMRRBuildService] s
```

Comment: great thanks, I feel silly :)